# Nice general way to always invoke python debugger upon exception

Tags: python, vim, exception, pdb, pudb

I'd like to have my debugger run `post_mortem()` any time an exception is encountered, *without* having to modify the source that I'm working on. I see lots of examples that involve wrapping code in a try/except block, but I'd like to have it always run, regardless of what I'm working on.

I worked on a python wrapper script but that got to be ugly and pretty much unusable.

I use [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), which is API-equivalent to pdb, so a pdb-specific answer is fine. I run code from within my editor (vim) and would like to have the pm come up any time an exception is encountered.

Answer (score 7):

It took a few months of not doing anything about it, but I happened to stumble upon a solution. I'm sure this is nothing new for the more experienced.

I have the following in my environment:

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=~/.python
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PYTHONUSERBASE
```

And I have the following file:

```
~/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usercustomize.py
```

With the following contents:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    import pudb as debugger
except ImportError:
    import pdb as debugger

def drop_debugger(type, value, tb):
  traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
  debugger.pm()

sys.excepthook = drop_debugger

__builtins__['debugger'] = debugger
__builtins__['st'] = debugger.set_trace
```

Now, whether interactively or otherwise, the debugger always jumps in upon an exception. It might be nice to smarten this up some.

It's important to make sure that you have no `no-global-site-packages.txt` in your `site-packages`. This will disable the `usercustomize` module with the default `site.py` (my virtualenv had a `no-global-site-packages.txt`)

Just in case it would help others, I left in the bit about modifying `__builtins__`. I find it quite handy to always be able to rely on some certain tools being available.

Flavor to taste.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD.   Yes. <3<3<3

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to invoke `pdb` (I don't know about `pudb`, but I'll just assume it works the same) as a script:

```
python -m pdb script.py
```

Quoting the [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

> When invoked as a script, pdb will automatically enter post-mortem
>   debugging if the program being debugged exits abnormally. After
>   post-mortem debugging (or after normal exit of the program), pdb will
>   restart the program.

Comment: Yes. That's what the docs say, but if I run that, even on a tivial script, I always enter the debugger:

    $ echo '' > /tmp/x.py && python -m pdb /tmp/x.py
    > /tmp/x.py(1)<module>()
    ->
    (Pdb)

Comment: You're right, the program doesn't start immediately. You could add a `.pdbrc` file containing `continue` in you home or project directory, but unfortunately this is [only supported since 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pdb.html#module-pdb)

Comment: It looks like that's one significant difference from pudb. There's no ".pudbrc".

Comment: Under `pdb`, [since 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pdb.html#module-pdb) the script **does start immediately** when I run `python3 -m pdb -c c script.py`, no need for a `.pdbrc` file or any changes to the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for `pdb` **since Python 3.2** is to start the program under the debugger via `-m pdb` and tell pdb to continue via `-c c`:

```
python3 -m pdb -c c program.py
```

Quoting [the pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pdb.html):

> When invoked as a script, pdb will automatically enter post-mortem debugging if the program being debugged exits abnormally. After post-mortem debugging (or after normal exit of the program), pdb will restart the program.

**As-of pudb 2019.2**: according to [the pudb documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pudb/usage.html), the official way involves changing your code a bit (and even then, I don't end up in post-mortem mode if I just run `python3 program.py`!):

> To start the debugger without actually pausing use:
>
> `from pudb import set_trace; set_trace(paused=False)`
>
> at the top of your code. This will start the debugger without breaking, and run it until a predefined breakpoint is hit. You can also press b on a set_trace call inside the debugger, and it will prevent it from stopping there.

Although it is possible to start the program properly under the debugger via `python3 -m pudb.run program.py`, pudb's command-line args do not support anything like pdb's `-c c`. The pudb's `--pre-run=COMMAND` is for external commands, not pudb commands.

What I currently do is run `python3 -m pudb.run program.py` without mentioning `pudb` or `set_trace`in `program.py` at all and press `c` on the keyboard. This way pudb enters its post-mortem mode upon any unhandled exception. This however only works well when I know that the exception will be reproduced. For hunting down sporadically occuring exceptions I go back to the pdb solution.

Comment: Theres a lot of references to pudb; did you mean pdb?

Comment: [pudb](https://documen.tician.de/pudb/index.html) is a console-based visual debugger for python, which has some similarities to the well-known `pdb` but is really a separate thing. The question was about both `pdb` and `pudb` and so were the answers.